# How to convert a column base table into a row base table

Tags: mysql, sql

I need a hand how to construct a result table from the below source table.

Source table:

```
+-----+-------+--------+-----------+ 
| Cat | Data_1| Data_2 | Group_Idx |
+-----+-------+--------+-----------+
| 1-1 |  A11  |  B11   |     1     |
| 1-2 |  A12  |  B12   |     1     |
| 1-3 |  A13  |  B13   |     1     |
| 2-1 |  A21  |  B21   |     2     |
| 2-2 |  A22  |  B22   |     2     |
| 2-3 |  A23  |  B23   |     2     |
| 3-1 |  A31  |  B31   |     3     |
| 3-2 |  A32  |  B32   |     3     |
| 3-3 |  A33  |  B33   |     3     |
+-----+-------+--------+-----------+
```

Result table:

```
+-----+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| Idx | C_1_A | C_1_B | C_2_A | C_2_B | C_3_A | C_3_B |
+-----+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|  1  |  A11  |  B11  |  A21  |  B21  |  A31  |  B31  |
|  2  |  A12  |  B12  |  A22  |  B22  |  A32  |  B32  |          
|  3  |  A13  |  B13  |  A23  |  B23  |  A33  |  B33  |
+-----+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

In source table column Cat, e.g. 1-1's data will show under result table columns' C_1_A and C_1_B and Idx 1.

E.g. Cat 3-3's data will show under result table's columns C_3_A and C_3_B

My approach:

1. Since I knew ahead of time from the source table of the Group_Idx e.g. 3 is the max number of the Group_Idx. So I insert 3 blank rows of data into the result table like this:

   ```
   +-----+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
   | Idx | C_1_A | C_1_B | C_2_A | C_2_B | C_3_A | C_3_B |
   +-----+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
   |  1  |       |       |       |       |       |       |
   |  2  |       |       |       |       |       |       |          
   |  3  |       |       |       |       |       |       |
   +-----+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
   ```
2. I use SUBSTRING to target the source table's Cat column e.g. 1-3, SUBSTRING('1-3',1,1) = 1 which is the result column C_1_A that I will be targeting to.

   Problems: How to dynamically or use if condition to switch which column to update (result table).
3. Then I try to use another SUBSTRING to target which row of the result table for update: SUBSTRING('1-3',3,1) = 3. This should be the last portion of the SQL where clause.

   ```sql
   CREATE TABLE source(Cat VARCHAR(5), Data_1 VARCHAR(5), Data_2 
   VARCHAR(5), Group_Idx VARCHAR(5));

   INSERT INTO source(Cat, Data_1, Data_2, Group_Idx) values ('1-1' 
   , 'A11', 'B11', '1');
   INSERT INTO source(Cat, Data_1, Data_2, Group_Idx) values ('1-2' 
   , 'A12', 'B12', '1');
   INSERT INTO source(Cat, Data_1, Data_2, Group_Idx) values ('1-3' 
   , 'A13', 'B13', '1');
   INSERT INTO source(Cat, Data_1, Data_2, Group_Idx) values ('2-1' 
   , 'A21', 'B21', '2');
   INSERT INTO source(Cat, Data_1, Data_2, Group_Idx) values ('2-2' 
   , 'A22', 'B22', '2');
   INSERT INTO source(Cat, Data_1, Data_2, Group_Idx) values ('2-3' 
   , 'A23', 'B23', '2');
   INSERT INTO source(Cat, Data_1, Data_2, Group_Idx) values ('3-1' 
   , 'A31', 'B31', '3');
   INSERT INTO source(Cat, Data_1, Data_2, Group_Idx) values ('3-2' 
   , 'A32', 'B32', '3');
   INSERT INTO source(Cat, Data_1, Data_2, Group_Idx) values ('3-3' 
   , 'A33', 'B33', '3');

   CREATE TABLE result(Idx VARCHAR(5), C_1_A VARCHAR(5), C_1_B 
   VARCHAR(5), C_2_A VARCHAR(5), C_2_B VARCHAR(5), C_3_A 
   VARCHAR(5), C_3_B VARCHAR(5));

   INSERT INTO result(Idx) values ('1');
   INSERT INTO result(Idx) values ('2');
   INSERT INTO result(Idx) values ('3');
   ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation.  I can't tell if you want the third character of the `cat` to define the columns in the result, or just to order the categories.  This takes the latter approach:

```
select group_idx,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then data_1 end) as c_1_a,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then data_2 end) as c_1_b,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then data_1 end) as c_2_a,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then data_2 end) as c_2_b,
       max(case when seqnum = 3 then data_1 end) as c_3_a,
       max(case when seqnum = 3 then data_2 end) as c_3_b
from (select s.*,
             row_number() over (partition by group_idx order by cat) as seqnum
      from source s
     ) s
group by group_idx;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6ccfab84c07919fd321b831c299535f4) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, I won't need the cat data in the result table and let me try out your code. Thanks very much.

Comment: Tried but with errors: select Group_Idx, max(case when seqnum = 1 then Data_1 end) as C_1_A, max(case when seqnum = 1 then Data_2 end) as C_1_B, max(case when seqnum = 2 then Data_1 end) as C_2_A, max(case when seqnum = 2 then Data_2 end) as C_2_B, max(case when seqnum = 3 then Data_1 end) as C_3_A, max(case when seqnum = 3 then Data_2 end) as C_3_B from (select 
 *,row_number() over (partition by Group_Idx order by Cat) as seqnum from source s) s group by Group_Idx; Error: SQL syntax; use near '(partition by Group_Idx order by Cat) as seqnum from source s)group by Group_Idx'

Comment: @LHLK . . . You don't specify what the error is.  I added a db<>fiddle showing that the code works.  This does require MySQL 8+.

Comment: I'm using 10.1.38-MariaDB  let me check if it's the same as MySql 8+. Maybe the partiion by didn't support ?

Comment: Ok I think your code is working and I think row_number() only started support with 10.2 of MariaDB. Let me check again. Hey thanks very much.

Comment: Hi Gordon, I upgraded the DB version and I confirmed that your solution works. Many thanks again. Even though I'd no idea how exactly this SQL statement work but I will look into it.